# How to add NG Prime schedule (calendar) component dynamically in Angular 4/5

Tags: angular, primeng

In my job I have a task where I have to add many NG [Prime-calendars](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) into webpage and need to exchange information among them. It seems that it is not enough in such case just to add component in a typical way i.e.:

```
<p-schedule id="cal1" [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" [height]="700" [styleClass]="'schedule-width'"></p-schedule>
<p-schedule id="cal2" [events]="events2" [header]="headerConfig2" [height]="700" [styleClass]="'schedule-width'"></p-schedule>
```

.. etc.

I need to also be able to dynamically loop through them and catch them individually by id and manipulate them via code. Does anyone know how to get this calendar component into variable and / or create dynamically calendar components via code in Angular 4/5? I am trying to figure this out from the api-documentation but there seem not to be examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an array of schedule events and configs. Let's name this array `schedules`. It will contain as many items as calendars you want and each item will be an object composed of events and a headerConfig.

```
this.schedules = [
    { 
      // first calendar
      events: [
        {
            "title": "All Day Event",
            "start": "2018-03-01"
        },
        {
            "title": "Long Event",
            "start": "2018-03-07",
            "end": "2018-03-10"
        }
      ],
      headerConfig: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          }
    },
    // second calendar
    // ...
  } 
]
```

Then, in your HTML component, just loop this `schedules` array like that :

```
<div *ngFor="let schedule of schedules;let i = index">
  <p-schedule #fc id="cal{{i}}" [events]="schedule.events" [header]="schedule.headerConfig" [height]="700" [styleClass]="'schedule-width'"></p-schedule><br/>
</div>
```

---

**Edit :**

In order to access your calendars in TS code, you can use [ViewChildren decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) (don't forget to add `#fc` to your `p-schedule` in HTML) :

```
@ViewChildren("fc") fcs: QueryList<any>;
```

Then, you can update view (for instance) of all calendars like that :

```
    this.fcs.forEach(fc => {
      fc.changeView('agendaDay');
    });
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hY9UxYM3pF5BfYOzEG7Y?p=preview)

Comment: This approach works otherwise but when I try to catch the schedule objects in the ts-code to change the view type of all calendars: 
      for (let calendar of this.calendars) {
        let calendarObj:any = document.getElementById(calendar.calID)
        calendarObj.fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
      }, I get error: ERROR TypeError: calendarObj.fullCalendar is not a function. Note that I have added ids to the array of calendar objects.

Comment: You can manage this by using `ViewChildren` decorator (see my edit section)

Comment: Well, now it really starts looking like there is a solution for this, so thank you so far. I may have to yet resort to your expertise a bit later so I leave this question yet open for a period of having tested this in other scenarios  I must implement closely related to previous one.

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate if you have more questions.